# How to prioritize which components in a circuit gets power

Tags: power

I'm sure this is probably very simple.

I have 2 power connections - a 5V 24A DC and a 5V 5A DC - a RasPi (1A power draw?) and the setup it's connected to (25A power draw). Normally both connections would be connected together and we'd have a total 29A which is enough for the entire circuit.

Sometimes, we might have to disconnect one of the connections temporarily - which in both cases means there's insufficient power - in that case I still want the RasPI to be guaranteed its 1A of power and the rest of the circuit uses the remaining power (they're just LEDs, and worst case they shut off until both power connections are available again; whereas the RasPi shutting down could mean data loss).

How do I do that?

Comment: I did not understand one part: have you connected two 5V power supplies, 24A and 5A, together in parallel, to create a 5V 29A power supply?

Comment: I think you should just find a way to turn off the LED's before you disconnect one of the supplies. Trying to make it happen reliably and automatically when someone disconnects one of the supplies is not so easy.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that needs to be dealt with ahead of time and designed/discussed at the system design level.

Comment: @mkeith we don't need the leds to be turned off entirely - the whole thing should still work even with the insufficient power, just a lot dimmer. we just want the raspi to get the power it needs first. this is new - i haven't built this yet - so open to options.

Comment: You must reduce the load below supply limits at all costs to avoid failure. Sharing supplies here is not a solution.  Getting more supplies distributed to all loads and account for all cable loss may be needed.

Comment: It's meant to be temporary, it's a battery that has 2 outputs and we want to be able to change batteries on the fly by switching 1 output over at a time. We just don't want the pi to shut down in the few seconds that only one connection is attached. If this scenario isn't possible I guess we could just build in 4 inputs so during the swap both batteries are connected, but I figured it was something simple I was blanking on. :)

Comment: Can you draw the setup?

Comment: Your question says 5 V power supplies. Your comment says, "it's a battery that has two outputs". Which is it? Hit the edit link below your question, add a schematic (there's a button on the editor toolbar) and give part numbers and links to datasheets.

Comment: I'm new to this kind of project and not super familiar with how to do that correctly. I'm trying to use this battery: PB240B1 on Amazon, using 2x 12/24v to 5v step-down converters to get both of its outputs to 5v, combining the 2 to have 1 29a 5v output, and was just going to connect both LEDs and RasPi to that output - I've tried something similar on another project and it worked. I was just curious if there was a way to improve on that.

Comment: So paralleling two supplies is a task unto itself. There are a lot of details to see to if you want to operate two supplies in parallel. But you seem to have an idea that a supply will back-off gracefully when it is presented with an overload. That is usually not the case. The supply will much more likely crash and take the whole system down with it. SO, for an automatic solution, you need to notify the system that a supply is about to be disconnected, and the system must dim or turn off the LED's before either supply is disconnected.

Comment: Question: Can the Raspberry Pi adjust the LED brightness or turn them off programmatically?

Comment: One solution might be to use a connector with an extra pin or two pins for "presence detect." Then, in code, you monitor presence detect and turn off or dim the LED's when either supply presence detect is de-asserted. You would need to poll those IO's pretty frequently and react with low latency. Not sure the Pi is up to that. So the other option would be to have presence detect be connected to a switch so that all LED's are turned off instantly any time either supply is disconnected.

Comment: It can adjust in software, but it'd be more work than it's worth. I was just hoping there was some simple circuit that did this.. the RPI forums suggest using a mini UPS breakout board, which I guess is close enough.

Comment: Well, you haven't really painted a complete picture so it is hard to be sure what to tell you. Anyway, hope it all works out.